# Variable inside a loop being set to the next array's element has the same memory address all the time?

Tags: c++, pointers

Let's consider a little program like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    int i, j, k;
} ThreeDPoint;

int main() {
    ThreeDPoint p[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        p[i].i = i * 3;
        p[i].j = i * 3 + 1;
        p[i].k = i * 3 + 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "i = " << i << endl;
        ThreeDPoint lp = p[i];
        cout << "&p[" << i << "] = " << (long) &lp << endl;
        cout << "&p[" << i << "].i = " << (long) &lp.i << endl;
        cout << "p[" << i << "].i = " << (long) lp.i << endl;
        cout << "&p[" << i << "].j = " << (long) &lp.j << endl;
        cout << "p[" << i << "].j = " << (long) lp.j << endl;
        cout << "&p[" << i << "].k = " << (long) &lp.k << endl;
        cout << "p[" << i << "].k = " << (long) lp.k << endl;
    }
}
```

Variable named `lp` is updated to have a value of a structure inside an array and being updated with the `i` variable inside the loop. I expect that if, for instance, first element (`p[0]`) starts at memory location `100`, then the second element (`p[1]`) will start from `112`, assuming that `sizeof(int) == 4` is true.

It is not the case, though: the printed value informs that the variable is actually updated to contain the next structure value all the time, but it seems that it, for some reason, has the same memory address (for `i = 0` `&p[i].i == 100`, for `i = 1` `&p[i].i == 100`, too). What's interesting is that if the intermediate variable `lp` is removed and `p[i]` is accessed directly, then I see the expected memory addresses to be printed out (for `i = 0` `&p[i].i == 100`, for `i = 1` `&p[i].i == 112`). Here are the logs:

> i = 0
>
> &p[0] = 140736159721040
>
> &p[0].i = 140736159721040
>
> p[0].i = 0
>
> &p[0].j = 140736159721044
>
> p[0].j = 1
>
> &p[0].k = 140736159721048
>
> p[0].k = 2
>
> i = 1
>
> &p[1] = 140736159721040
>
> &p[1].i = 140736159721040
>
> p[1].i = 3
>
> &p[1].j = 140736159721044
>
> p[1].j = 4
>
> &p[1].k = 140736159721048
>
> p[1].k = 5
>
> i = 2
>
> &p[2] = 140736159721040
>
> &p[2].i = 140736159721040
>
> p[2].i = 6
>
> &p[2].j = 140736159721044
>
> p[2].j = 7
>
> &p[2].k = 140736159721048
>
> p[2].k = 8

Why is that? Why is the value updated but the memory location is the same? Is this some kind of g++ optimization that is performed after variables usage analysis?

Comment: `ThreeDPoint lp = p[i];` -- The `lp` variable is its own entity.  It has no association with the `p` array after that statement is executed.

Comment: when you are assing the `ThreeDPoint lp = p[i];` you are copy the contest of `p[i]` to `ThreeDPoint lp` so, your code is printig the addresses related to local vairalbe `lp`. Instead of copy, trhought the copy operatos, the strcuture  `ThreeDPoint` try to copy the pointer of each item of the array:  `ThreeDPoint* lp = p + i;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the address of the variable, not the address of your array elements. The variable and the array don't have the same address (obviously) and it's quite reasonable (but not guaranteed) that the same address would be reused for the variable each time around the loop.

To print the address of the array element try this

```
cout << "&p[" << i << "] = " << &p[i] << endl;
```

I guess your misunderstanding is that you think

```
ThreeDPoint lp = p[i];
```

somehow makes `lp` *point* to the array element. But it doesn't, it *copies* the array element and stores a copy in the variable.